# SQL query 'inner join'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table in my SQL Server database:

```
CREATE TABLE HISTORICO
(
    CODIGO VARCHAR(255),
    FECHA VARCHAR(255),
    VALOR VARCHAR(255),
);
```

The PK is composed of `CODIGO` and `FECHA`.

What I am looking for is to obtain all the records filtered by CODE and also for the DATE to exist in all the records of the same code. I attach a graphic example:

I want all records where the code is "AAA" but also exist (by DATE) in "BBB" and in "CCC".

That is, where the date is also the same for all `CODIGO`.

[image]

I write the query that I currently use and it works correctly.

[image]

I think it can be done better, although right now I can't find a way.
Does somey know how to improve the query obtaining the same result?

Comment: What is a "concrete query"? How does it differ from a "normal" query.

Comment: An `EXISTS`? A windowed `COUNT`?

Comment: You don't have a date here. You do have a varchar(255) with what appears to be integer data that might be a year. This begs the question, why are you storing the year as a varchar(255)? You should use int for integers. But do you not care anything about the data other than the year?

Comment: Shortest what? Execution time?

Comment: Please don't use images for data or queries, use formatted text.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but it seems you can use the `WITH TIES` option in concert with the window function `row_number()`

```
Select top 1 with ties *
 From YourTable
 Order by row_number() over (partition by codigo order by Fecha)
```

Comment: I'm not sure this meets the requirements (as I've understood them)... i.e. if you added a row with CODIGO='AAA' and FECHA='2021' then that row would be returned for CODIGO instead of the 2022 row.

Answer (score -1):

I would guess you want to look for sets that include all `FECHA` values.

You can do:

```
select * from t where codigo in (
  select codigo from t group by codigo having count(distinct fecha) = 3
)
```

Change `3` by the number of `FECHA` you want to check.

Comment: This is a great solution where the number of possible values for CODIGO is known in advance.  Note though: I believe CODIGO and FECHA are the wrong way around for the requirement (assuming I've understood the requirements correctly).

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is what you're after: [SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c44fb/2)

```sql
select *
from HISTORICO
where FECHA in 
(
  select FECHA
  from HISTORICO
  group by FECHA
  having count(distinct CODIGO) = (
    select count(distinct CODIGO) 
    from HISTORICO
  )
)
-- update per comments
and CODIGO = 'AAA'
-- end of update
order by FECHA, CODIGO
```

### Explanation

The innermost query figures out how many distinct values for CODIGO exist in the table.  Since you only want records where every existing value of CODIGO has a matching value of FECHA we need to know how many CODIGO values there are in total.

The next layer up returns all values of FECHA for which every value of CODIGO exists; it does this by grouping all FECHA records then counting the number of different (distinct) values of CODIGO are in that set, and comparing that to the number we calculated earlier.

The outermost query returns all records which have this FECHA value; since those are the ones we care about.

Note: there may be more efficient solutions to this out there; I've just knocked up a first pass at what should meet your functional requirement.  If you have an index of FECHA (idealy your primary key & clustered index contains FECHA followed by CODIGO) this should perform pretty well.

### Your Requirements

Just in case there's any confusion, here's how I understood your requirement - please say if this is incorrect, as if it is this solution won't be appropriate:

You want to:

- return all records
- where for a given value of FECHA
- there exists a record with that FECHA value for every possible value of CODIGO

Note: "every possible value of CODIGO" is based on the values that exist across the HISTORICO table itself; i.e. if we were to delete the records where CODIGO='CCC' then all records would be returned, since both AAA and BBB have values with FECHA 2022 and 2023, and there would be no other values of CODIGO (based on the sample data in your screenshots.

Comment: I have tried the query, it is practically what I am looking for but I would like to only show the results with code 'AAA'

Comment: AAA    2022 1 (only this row) Thanks a lot

Comment: No worries; please see updated solution (i.e. I've added a line to filter for codigo = AAA)

Comment: Great, it's what I needed! I couldn't get it without an infinite number of inner Joins
Many thanks friends